# PWA Deeplink not open in Standalone

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I've a Wordpress PWA based on https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/ .
The users of the app can scan a NFC-Sticker which open a Deeplink and pass an ID to the App e.g. https://myapp.domain.com/id=1234

Unfortunately sometimes the PWA did not open in the standalone mode, which is defined in the Manifest. To force this, i've integrated a php header redirection which open the PWA in most cases.

Any ideas?